# unable to find Paragon NTFS for Western Digital(WD) external drives

Tags: macos, external-disk, apfs, ntfs, hdd

I have had Paragon NTFS 15's free version for Western Digital Drives. Just like Seagate offers. Somehow I had to erase my MacBook Pro and the software has been deleted. So now I am unable to find it on the web. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two options. The first is to use the [paid software from Paragon Software](https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/ntfs-mac/). While it is not free, it appears to be the most compatible option going forward.

Western Digital also has a [link to an older version of NTFS for Mac](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19554#subject2). Keep in mind that the new NTFS for Mac looks to be compatible with macOS 10.14 where WD’s software lists compatibility up to 10.12.

They have a link to a more recent version of Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac (15.9.328, 2021-10-21) on [My Passport Wireless Pro's download page](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/261#WD_downloads). The driver also works for other models.

Paragon Software does say in their FAQ that you may be eligible for an upgrade from WD or Seagate’s older versions of NTFS for Mac.

> **I’m a user of a Seagate or Western Digital device with pre-installed
> NTFS for Mac. How can I get my update?**
>
> You are eligible for a special update for you current version of
> Microsoft NTFS for Mac by Paragon Software. Please contact our Support
> Service at support@paragon-software.com to reclaim your update.

Source: [NTFS for Mac FAQ](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/#faq)

Comment: The latest version for WD drives appears to be available here: https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/261#WD_downloads

Comment: A dedicated (un)installation tutorial from WD can be found on https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/34871/kw/NTFS%20Driver%20for%20Mac

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Paragon NTFS Driver for Mac (15.9.328, 2021-10-21) can be downloaded from https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/261

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321891)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mounty](https://mounty.app/):

*A tiny tool to re-mount write-protected NTFS volumes under macOS in read-write mode. Supports macOS from version 10.9 Mavericks till 10.15 Catalina.*

Answer (score 0):

Paragon Support sent me this link to download the latest version when I requested the special update mentioned on their website.

[NTFS-15.5.66.dmg](https://dl.paragon-software.com/APC/WD/NTFS4Mac/15.5.66/NTFS-15.5.66.dmg)

Comment: Is this the special version for WD-drives? The link path suggests this...

Comment: The NTFS-15.5.66.dmg linked below only supports OS X 10.10-10.15. Do you happen to have a newer, Big Sur compatible version?